# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used React few month ago, now when I tried to use that code, made some changes in webpack config I'm getting errors.
I changed react-router to react-router-dom.
Whole routes file is here
https://github.com/mstanielewicz/react-simple-boilerplate/blob/master/app/config/routes.js
I'm getting:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in.

I went through the code a few time and don't see any errors. Components and Containers are defined and exported correctly.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  hashHistory,
  IndexRoute,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { MainContainer, HomeContainer } from 'containers'

export default function getRoutes() {
  return (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Router path='/' component={MainContainer} >
          <IndexRoute component={HomeContainer} />
      </Router>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Directory structure looks like this

```
- app
  |_components
  |  |_Home
  |  |_index.js
  |_containers
     |_Main
     |_Home
     |_index.js
```

with exports like this

```
export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'
export HomeContainer from './Home/HomeContainer'
```

And webpack cfg

```
var path = require('path')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.html'),
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body',
})

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    './app/index.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig],
}
```

Anyone can see a problem here?

Comment: Plz include relevant code to the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a problem of `import` to me.

In react-router-dom, `Router` as been replaced by `BrowserRouter`. Or may be a bad `default export`, for example

```
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom
```

instead of

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

---

### EDIT :

Your exports seems a bit weird. 
Try to change `import { MainContainer, HomeContainer } from 'containers'` into

```
import MainContainer from './containers/Main/MainContainer'
import HomeContainer from 'containers/Main/HomeContainer'
```

and `export default class FooContainer`  in the respective files.

There is also the fact you're using a `Router` inside a `Router`. Shouldn't it be a `Route` ?